# AngularJS and Bootstrap: ng-repeat and paginator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in Angular and Bootstrap and I can't figure out why following code is working fine:

```
<ul class="pagination"">
    <li ng-class=" { 'active': activePage==0,  'none': activePage!=0 }">
        <a ng-click="activePage=0">1 - 9</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class=" { 'active': activePage==1,  'none': activePage!=1 }">
        <a ng-click="activePage=1">10 - 19</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class=" { 'active': activePage==2,  'none': activePage!=2 }">
        <a ng-click="activePage=2">20 - 29</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class=" { 'active': activePage==3,  'none': activePage!=3 }">
        <a ng-click="activePage=3">30 - </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However if I want to do the same using ng-repeat - it doesn't update the activePage variable:

```
<ul class="pagination" ng-repeat="p in [0,1,2];">
    <li ng-class=" { 'active': activePage==p,  'none': activePage!=p }">
        <a ng-click="activePage=p">{{ (p*10)+1}} - {{ (p*10)+9 }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in addition, after click on element the style is stored on them permanently - it becomes active, and previously selected element is also active.

Do you have any clues what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are using `primitive` type value inside `ng-repeat`.  So what happens is whenever `ng-repeat` render template n times, each time it creates a new prototypically inherited scope for that iteration. So while creating a child scope it carries all the `primitive` values & object value with their reference to child scope. Since when you use do `activePage=p` inside `ng-repeat`'s `ng-click` directive, it does create new `activePage` variable inside `ng-repeat` scope. That's why each time you click any page it selects that even you click next item.

In such cases you should be using `Dot Rule`, where you can define module & then defined properties inside it. Basically advantage of using this approach is, now you will be passing reference of object while creating child scope.

```
<ul class="pagination" ng-repeat="p in [0,1,2]">
    <li ng-class="{ 'active': model.activePage==p, 'none': model.activePage!=p }">
        <a ng-click="model.activePage=p">{{ (p*10)+1}} - {{ (p*10)+9 }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.model = {
  activePage: 0
}
```

[**Forked Codeply**](http://www.codeply.com/go/CBLzxigNDl)

Answer (score 0):

The `ng-repeat` should be the `<li>` tag...

```
<ul class="pagination" ng-init="activePage=1">
    <li ng-class="{ 'active': activePage==p,  'none': activePage!=p }" ng-repeat="p in [0,1,2]">
        <a ng-click="activePage=p">{{ (p*10)+1}} - {{ (p*10)+9 }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/l0nyBT678O

Comment: No it's not - look at your example and click pagination buttons - active class is set after you click a button but it's not unset at another - so this class can be set at multiple buttons at the same time, which is not desired behaviour.